# php die() doesn't work (simply code)

Tags: php

I am learning how to use "setcookie", however, I couldn't get following line to work, 
I have pasted all my codes here, if someone could give me a hand please?
Have no idea the reason.
Many thanks.

```
  else{ die ("hahahahahahahahahahahahahaha"); }
```

HTML code

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<div class="error"><?php echo $error;?></div>
<p></p>
<label>Username: </label><br>
<input type="text" name="username"><br>
<label>Password: </label><br>
<input type="password" name="password"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="rememberme"> Remember me<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
```

PHP CODE

```
<?
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //get data
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $rememberme = isset($_POST['rememberme']);
    echo $rememberme;


    if($username&&$password){
    $login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM form WHERE username='$username'");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($login))
    {
        $db_password = $row['password'];
        if (md5($password)== $db_password)
        {
            $logstatus = TRUE;
            }
        else{
            $logstatus = FALSE; 
            }
        if ($logstatus == TRUE)
        {
            if ($rememberme == "1")
                setcookie("username", $username, time()+600);
            else if ($rememberme == "")
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;


        echo " I am here";
        }

        else{
           die ("hahahahahahahahahahahahahaha"); //unable to get here
        }
    }

}

    else{
    echo "enter username / password";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: you don't need a while() loop for 1 db row

Comment: is $logstatus being set to FALSE ? i.e. is the password matching the password passed in? If the die() isn't being called are you seeing the:  echo " I am here"; ?

Comment: Can u  print and check the $logstatus before the  if ($logstatus == TRUE)

Comment: 1) your not escaping your db parameters, this is dangerous. 2) md5 is not enough to protect passwords by itself... you need to make a seed and hash the password with it. 3) rememberme should be a boolean value based on isset($_POST[rememberme]), not a string value of '1', see: `var_dump($rememberme)` to confirm, not echo.

Comment: thanks. echo $logstatus; no output before if ($logstatus == TRUE)

Comment: Try `var_dump($logstatus)` instead. If `$logstatus` is false then you won't see any output with echo and so won't be sure if you're even in the `while` loop.

Comment: Which brings me to this ... are you sure you're even getting a result from your db query? You should add some basic error checking. And as others have said, you can skip the `while` loop if you're only expecting a single record from your query. You could instead use something like `if ($login && $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($login)) { /* do something */ } else { /* report error */ }`.

Comment: As an aside, don't use short tags - [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/)

Comment: So much teaching going on. Lovely!

Comment: @BrianS Logically, I can't see anything wrong, if it just doesnt go to die(); many thanks for your timely help

Comment: @olo it can be pretty easy to miss a mistake, especially if it's not in your PHP syntax. Plus, your logic would work so long as a recordset is returned. Always try to be as specific as possible about what you expect in your variables and test before use. Most PHP functions help by returning false when they fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, I haven't tested it but is should works :)

```
session_start();//dont forget this :P
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //get data
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $rememberme = isset($_POST['rememberme']);
    echo $rememberme;    
if($username&&$password){
    $login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM form WHERE username='$username' AND password='".md5($password)."'");


        if (mysql_num_rows($login))//if this returns 1 you are logged in
        {
            if ($rememberme == "1")
                setcookie("username", $username, time()+600);
            else
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;


                echo " I am here";              

        }else{
           die ("Incorrect Username/Password"); //unable to get here
        }
    }

}

    else{
    echo "enter username / password";
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code, Unluckly, I got this mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given ..... otherwise, it works!

Comment: then the problem is in your SQL query, check it =)

Comment: @olo that means there's something wrong with your query or your database connection. `$login` is probably `(boolean) FALSE` which could very well mean your [mysql_query() call failed](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php#refsect1-function.mysql-query-returnvalues). Are you connected to your database? I don't see anything in your example that indicates as much (though you are wise to exclude such details).

Comment: @olo if you're not sure, you can always check mysql_error() to see why your query failed. If either of your variables contain quotes that would be a problem. As mentioned by others, you *should* escape anything you send to your database that originates from a user. At the very least try `$login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM \`form\` WHERE \`username\`='" . mysql_real_escape_string($username) . "' AND \`password\`='" . md5($password) . "'");`

Comment: Thanks guys, yes, I include() my database external. I tried if ($login && $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($login)) { /* do something */ } else { /* report error */ } it works!! many thanks

Comment: one more question is should i use rememberme =="on" or "1", the output is 1. thanks

Comment: yes I have 2 lines, for escape, $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username); $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

Comment: @olo [isset()](refsect1-function.isset-returnvalues) returns TRUE or FALSE, so I would use `$rememberme == TRUE`.

Answer (score -1):

The while loop is causing the issue, simply remove it.

Answer (score -1):

Well I didn't tested the code but trying following might help.

Add line:

```
$logstatus = TRUE;
```

before while.

Justification:
Scope of variable finishes as soon as block finishes. defining logstatus outside while will make sure its scope do not end where it is required.

Comment: `while` and if-then-else blocks do not create a new scope in PHP.